# South Korea pre-reform postcodes dataset

Tags: data-request, postal-code, korea

"The Korea Postal code system changed from a 6-digit postal code system to a 5-digit postal code system on August 1, 2015" ([source](http://www.fedex.com/gy/koreapostalcode/index.html)). So if you look up for example the old "korea 110-744" or "korea 110744" on Google Maps or GeoNames.org, you draw a blank. But if you simply Google it, you do find references to gazetteer websites, such as http://south-korea.postcode.info/p/110-744.

Is there a good (ideally open) source of structured (machine-readable) geolocation (address and ideally long-lat) data for South Korea pre-reform postcodes (and ideally current ones as well)? The address could be romanised or in [hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul), but that would be indifferent if long-lat is provided. The goal is to geolocate (long-lat) a dataset of addresses going back to the 1980s.

Comment: Thanks! I asked here because of this [post](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4156/88704). Could my question be migrated there? Alternatively, I'm also interested in commercial sources, if no open data can be found. Should I then edit my question accordingly and keep it here?

Answer (score 1):

The Korean postal service offers downloads of the latest pre-reform postal codes here: https://www.epost.go.kr/search/zipcode/newAddressDown.jsp (page in Korean). The data takes the form of pipe-separated postal codes and addresses both romanized and in hangul. No latitude nor longitude.